# What does this error message mean?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sure  not sure why this is occuring, could some elaborate why i am getting this error message...

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342: error: no matching function for call to 'print(int, void*&, ros::console::Level&, const char [82], int, const char [60], std::string&)'
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

I tried to comment out my code, but can't seem locate where or what it is troubled with?
^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231798/what-does-this-error-message-mean?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-04-13**:
You might want to include your code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted the build and devel folder, and ran `catkin_make` again.

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0